# What does this text on a vase mean?

Tags: translation

We have recently received this vase as a gift from a business partner. I am very curious what this text on it means but am not in a position to ask them.

I wasn't able to use Google Translate (probably because it is handwriting) on it and I don't know anyone who speaks chinese. Could somebody here translate it for me please!

Thank you! 
[image: Vase]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text is read from top to bottom, right to left.

**First two columns:**

> 香遠溢清

Which means **As the aroma (of the flower, referring in particular to the lotus) goes further, it becomes more and more pure and fresh**. BTW, the artist mistakes 益(more and more) for 溢(overflow, spill). These two characters sound the same in Chinese. Maybe the artist was intentional, to express a different feeling from the original author of this phrase.

This phrase originates from Song Dynasty's litterateur 周敦頤's essay ***愛蓮說*** (Ode to the Lotus Flower).

> 水陸草木之花，可愛者甚蕃。晉陶淵明獨愛菊；自李唐來，世人盛愛牡丹；予獨愛蓮之出淤泥而不染，濯清漣而不妖，中通外直，不蔓不枝， **香遠益清** ，亭亭靜植，可遠觀而不可褻玩焉。予謂菊，花之隱逸者也；牡丹，花之富貴者也；蓮，花之君子者也。噫！菊之愛，陶後鮮有聞；蓮之愛，同予者何人；牡丹之愛，宜乎眾矣。

This essay is to praise the noble and unsullied characteristic of the lotus. So in Chinese culture, lotus flowers are often compared to gentlemen.

**The left text:**

> 癸巳年  彭湘龍  作於景德鎮一品畫苑

This is the artist's inscription.

- [癸巳年](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%99%B8%E5%B7%B3) is the year. It is 2013, according to the context.
- 彭湘龍 is the artist's name, Peng Xianglong.
- 作於景德鎮一品畫苑. Finished in 一品畫苑(the studio's name), 景德鎮([Jingdezhen Town](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingdezhen), a town that is called *Porcelain Capital*. It is very very famous.)

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: @Andris: you're welcome :-)

Comment: @Stan In the third line of 愛蓮說 you quoted, I think it should be `陶後鮮有聞` instead of `陶后鮮有聞`.

Comment: @johnchen902: you're right :) I've fixed it. Thanks!